# rubocop linting issue with grape-entity `format_with` method

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Strictly a linting error, not a functional error - rubocop raises a linting error on my format_with method. It wants me to do `format_with(:mongo_id)(&:to_s)` but that is not physically possible.

```
class Mongoid < Grape::Entity
  format_with(:mongo_id) { |id| id.to_s }
  expose :_id, as: :id, format_with: :mongo_id
  # ...
end
```

the following is the error message

`Style/SymbolProc: Pass '&:to_s' as an argument to 'format_with' instead of a block.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
format_with(:mongo_id, &:to_s)
```

Which is an accepted and working short version for your `method(:arg) { |id| id.to_s }`.

That's the syntactic sugar for calling `to_proc` on every element within the block.